# WIX Installer UI - How to create feature selection

Tags: vb.net, wix, visual-studio-2022

I created a WIX Installer without really knowing a ton about WIX.  I do like that I know what I am installing, where I am installing it, and how to create the setup application.  However - I can't seem to figure out how to give checkboxes for each feature.

For example, I set my program up to have 2 features:

```
<Feature Id="AdminClient" Title="Admin Client" Level="1">
</Feature>
<Feature Id="AppDB" Title="Application Database" Level="1">
</Feature>
```

For this application, I want the installation to allow the user to check the boxes of the stuff they want to install.  For example - quite often the user will already have an application database and I do not want to overwrite that database.

I will also be adding other optional features and would like to have selection options for those.

I've played around with WixUI_Advanced and WixUI_InstallDir - but didn't see a way to do it with either.  But, again, I'm not great at this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WixUI_FeatureTree` and `WixUI_Mondo` dialog sets expose a feature selection dialog.